# Passage in a proof of a lemma

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Here is a lemma and a proof given to me in class.

**Lemma**
If $M$ is a smooth manifold, $K\subseteq M$ a compact subset, $A\subset M$ an open set containing $K$< then there exists a compact-support smooth function $\chi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(M)$ such that $\mathrm{supp}\,\chi\subseteq A$ and $\chi\equiv 1$ on $K$.

*Proof* Let $B:=M\smallsetminus K$. $B$ is then open, so $\{A,B\}$ is a cover of $M$. It is also finite, thus locally finite, thus we can find a partition of unity $\{\phi_A,\phi_B\}$ such that $\phi_A+\phi_B\equiv1$ on all of $M$, $\mathrm{supp}\,\phi_A\subseteq A$ and $\mathrm{supp}\,\phi_B\subseteq B$. If we set $\chi:=\phi_A$, we have $\mathrm{supp}\,\chi\subseteq A$, and $\chi|_K\equiv1$, since $K\subseteq M\smallsetminus B$ whence $\phi_B|_K\equiv0,\chi|_K=\phi_A|_K=(1-\phi_B)|_K\equiv1-0=1$. We only need to make $\mathrm{supp}\,\chi$ compact, and it is here that I have the problematic passage. We are told to find an open set $A'$ such that $K\subseteq A'\subseteq A$ and $\overline{A'}$ is compact. Assuming this can be found, then if we construct the partition of unity from $\{\phi_{A'},\phi_B\}$ and set $\chi:=\phi_{A'}$, $\mathrm{supp}\,\chi$ will be contained in $\overline{A'}$, which is compact, and as the support is the closure of the set of non-zeros it is closed, and being closed in a compact set means compactness, hence the proof is concluded. $\hspace{2cm}\square$

How do I prove there exists such an $A'$? I mean, I can easily find an open set $A'$ satisfying the inclusion, but how do I find one that is relatively compact? Is it true that, given $M$ a manifold, $K$ a compact set in $M$ and $A$ an open set containing $K$, there is always a relatively compact open set in between the two?

Comment: By the way, does this lemma bear the name of a mathematician? Because I missed the lesson it was proved in, and a classmate of mine's notes call it «Lemma di Biase» (Biase's lemma), or so I seem to read, so do you know if it has a name?

Comment: Why the downvote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topological space is called *locally compact* if every point has a compact neighbourhood. The fact that you want to use is the following.

> Suppose $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, and $K \subset U \subset X$ where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open. Then there is a relatively compact set $V$ such that $K \subset V \subset \overline{V} \subset U$.

Note, $V$ relatively compact means that $\overline{V}$ is compact. The proof of this result is straightforward and can be found in Section $4.5$ of Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications* (second edition) for example.

As well as being Hausdorff, every topological manifold is locally Euclidean and therefore locally compact, so the above result applies to manifolds.

I would call the Lemma a smooth version of the Urysohn Lemma.

Comment: Um, "compact" and "neighborhood" do not go too well together in my mind, since "compact" implies closed, and "neighborhood" means "open set" to me. Perhaps I should review my definition of neighborhood. Would you expand on that?

Comment: Here a neighbourhood of $x$ is a set which contains an open set which contains $x$.

Comment: Oh, and «every topological manifold is locally Euclidean and therefore locally compact», i.e. every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is locally compact, so I can find a compact neighborhood of the image of that point which can be mapped back via the homeomorphism to a compact neighborhood of the starting point of the manifold. This was just for myself.

Comment: @MickG: I'm pretty sure the link you posted is to an illegally pirated copy of Folland's book.

Comment: Let's say I delete that comment and post a couple of screenshots with the relevant parts.
[1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NKPXw.png) and [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XoY27.png). That's all that's needed.